# jQuery trigger click on certain viewport width

Tags: jquery, triggers

I'm trying to trigger a click when viewport width gets below 640. I have a drop-down menu and I want it to be unrolled without clicking when width is below 640. I tried to use the following but without any results. Any ideas?

```
if($(document).width() < 640){
        $("li.has-dropdown.not-click:contains('users')").trigger('click');
    }
```

This solution also doesn't work for me:

```
if($(document).width() < 640){
        $("li.has-dropdown.not-click:contains('users')")[0].click();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are providing too litle information and no html markup, therefore the best i can do is make some markup myself and use my navigation

just like with any other mobile navigation u have some button that after clicking shows the navigation so do i, only in my case its the entire p tag within .mobile_menu when i click on it it will toggle the classes of the navigation look for navigation.js under this link http://goo.gl/Yr0fie and check the styles, if its for the purpose of responsive site the combination of them should help you

this is the script that i added only to the homepage

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        if($(window).width() < 640){
            $( ".mobile_menu p" ).trigger( "click" );
        }
});
</script>
```

so when you open homepage in window that is less than 640 width it will show the navigation automaticaly, but as soon as you open different page it stays collapsed

take a good look at js,css and markup I am sure it will point you in the right direction

T

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer but resizing window will not work in my scenario. I have a menu button, after clicking it enrolls. Desired behaviour: when screen is < 640, menu is already enrolled, one doesn't need to click it. So I want it to behave like it was already clicked :)